# Why is the Visual Studio Performance Profiler not displaying anything for the Frame Time and FPS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance-testing

I'm trying to do a quick performance analysis for my OpenGL program, but for some reason, the visual studio performance profiler is not displaying anything for the frame time or FPS:

[image: VS]

It displays results for the GPU and CPU usage, but not the aforementioned. I thought maybe it might have had something to do with G-Sync being enabled globally, so I disabled it in the NVidia Control Panel, but there has been no change.

Can anyone provide me with information as to why it might not be working?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Performance Profiler shows GPU usage stats of DirectX applications. [OpenGL is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/gpu-usage).

Comment: Oh damn. Is there any way to get these results using another program or via some code?

Comment: @AndrewCoates See [Debugging Tools](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debugging_Tools).